# form post using a link (with no submit button)

Tags: forms, jakarta-ee, submit

In my javaee application,I want to show a listing of items to the user and also let the user edit quantity of the items by entering value in a text field and  clicking an 'update' link.I used doGet() in servlet for showing the listing of items.

Since update of an item is a modifying operation,I thought it should be in doPost() of the servlet.
I have seen most form submission done by clicking a submit button..But ,I am wondering if I can do the submission of data using a link

Similarly ,I want to let the user remove items by clicking on Remove links.

Please tell me how I can write this jsp code,sothat clicking on 'Update' link would call doPost() of my servlet

```
<c:url value="viewcart" var="updateqtyurl">

</c:url>
<td>
<input type="text" name="quantity" value="${cartitem.quantity }"><a href="${updateqtyurl}">update</a>

</td>


<c:url value="viewcart" var="removefromcarturl">
    <c:param name="bookToRemoveId" value="${cartitem.book.book_id}" />
</c:url>
<td>
<a href="${removefromcarturl}" ><img src="remove.png" alt="Remove"></a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add something like this in your Update link:

```
<a href="javascript:itemsForm.submit()">Update</a>
```

itemsForm is the id of the form containing the textfields

Comment: thanks for that one..but is it possible to do without javascript?